# ASP.NET MVC how to send bind object along with an array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC project with Entity Framework

I have 2 models:

- `ModelA` (string name, ICollection list)
- `ModelB` (int days)

Is there any way I can send an array of JSON (or better yet, the list of objects) to my controller, along with the bound attributes?

I've tried to sent the whole object as JSON and it worked, but I wonder if ASP.NET MVC has a tool to do this a better way.

chatGPT told me I could do this using jQuery:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateWithInstalment(
    [Bind("Name,Fee,Discount,Fine,Id")] PaymentCondition paymentCondition,
    [FromBody] List<InstalmentDTO> instalmentDTOList)
{
}
```

The submit:

```html
<input type="submit" 
       onclick="SendInstalmentArray();"
       value="Create" 
       class="btn btn-primary" />
```

The array:

```js
arrayInstalments.push({ Number, Days, Percentage, PaymentMethodId });
```

jQuery:

```js
function SendInstalmentArray() {
  console.log("sending array...");
  if (ValidateObject()) {
    setPaymentCondition();
    $.ajax({
       contentType: 'application/json',
       dataType: 'json',
       type: 'POST',
       url: "/PaymentConditions/CreateWithInstalment",
       data: JSON.stringify(arrayInstalments),
       success: function () {
       console.log("array sent");
      },
      error: function () {
        console.log("error on sending array");
      }
   });
 }
}
```

I see that the result is error 415, I'm sending 2 requests, and it doesn't work, but I don't know how could I do it better using ASP.NET tools instead of JSON to send the whole thing

Comment: Sending data as json is a completely normal way to send data in asp.net. This is not a problem. If you are saying you don't want to use jquery you can post your data with traditional form submits too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1

Comment: After testing, we found the FromBody cannot work with BindAttribute together. We suggest you may use [FromForm] to bind the properties and [FromBody] to bind the list in one action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i researched, i found out that what Ronaldoz said is true, so what i did that helped solve the problem:

I added into the binded  to send the array in the same request:

`enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="formList" data-list-name="instalmentList"`

then i made a hidden input and wrote the Json array into it to read and send it together, then on submit button i created a function:

`<input type="hidden" name="instalmentList" id="instalmentList" value="" />`

`<input type="submit" value="Create" onsubmit="UpdateHiddenArray();" class="btn btn-primary" />`

the function (arrayInstalments is the array with the wanted list):

```
        function UpdateHiddenArray() {
            instalmentsJson = JSON.stringify(arrayInstalments);
            $("#instalmentList").val(instalmentsJson);
            document.querySelector("#instalmentList").value = instalmentsJson;
        }
```

finally, on the controller i requested the array and transformed into the class DTO:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateWithInstalment([Bind("Name,Fee,Discount,Fine,Id")] PaymentCondition paymentCondition)
        {
            var jsonInstalmentList = Request.Form["instalmentList"];
            var instalmentList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InstalmentDTO>>(jsonInstalmentList);

            ...
        }
```

This worked for me, i got the object the usual bind object asp.net way, and then i got my list